# using setTimeout to execute function excatly at specified time

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my code below..

```
setTimeout(executeQuery, 5000);
```

Iam aware that `executeQuery` will run after 5 second... but I want to run it exactly at `e.getHours()+':'+e.getMinutes()` where
  `console.log(e.getHours()+':'+e.getMinutes());` will display `1:30` ,Iam trying to run a a function `today at 1:30` anyways to fix this???

Comment: Work out the number of ms between now and the time you want, then set the timeout delay to that.

Comment: oh sounds good.. let me try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the date and time when you want to run the function using `new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);` . Get the current `new Date()` , and substract the difference in their milliseconds count, assign it to the setTimeout function. See the following snippet:-

```
 window.onload=function(){
  var date1=new Date();
  var date2=new Date(2014,05,27,11,45,00);
  var diff=date2.getTime()-date1.getTime();
  setTimeout(executeQuery, diff);
  }
 function executeQuery(){
  alert("hello");
  }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A37KF/)

Comment: This will run the function literally today - but it would require editing if you ever want to use it in future. Not a great solution, IMO.

Comment: Ofcourse you have to edit and enter the date , or you can modify it to take time input from user, you are free to experiment. But you have to specify time in any case, its not intuitive.

Comment: Did you really just write that? Javascript knows what the date is today, how is having to re-deploy EVERY SINGLE DAY even slightly acceptable?

Comment: I am well aware of that, but what if you want to run the function at a particular date and time (both), what if the user deploys the code say at 11:59 pm to run the next day at 1 pm, the solution you say is restricted to today, Although I know the user wants to run the solution at particular time of today , but I gave a more generic solution, which will work for today, tommo, day after tommo, etc.  I am not here to provide an exact pin point working code which user copy-pastes and gets going  , I am trying to show the user a direction from when on he can experiment and modify code to his needs

Comment: Your solution is not generic, it is incredibly specific. It runs the code only at 11:45am on the 27th of June, 2014. Mine runs it at 1:30am (the requested time) today (or in fact any day) - as requested by the question asker. If he wanted code that would run exactly once ever, your answer would be correct. He did not, however, specify that, so a more robust and reusable solution is required. Your logic with regards to getting the difference is fine, but you are missing half of the answer.

Comment: The first part of my answer explains what to do, the second part (added many hours before you posted that comment) give a precise example on how to add that functionality if it is required, just in case it wasn't obvious.

Comment: Ah thats great, did not see that, but still my solution is not wrong, you just have to modify it according to your needs, and its meant to be more as an example than a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straight forward:

```
var today = new Date();
var target = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), 1, 30, 0);
var timeout = target.getTime() - new Date().getTime();    // today variable is slightly out of date by now, if that matters

setTimeout(executeQuery, timeout);
```

Basically you just get the milliseconds for today and your target date, then the difference is what you need to set your timeout to :).

EDIT: Keep in mind that `1:30` is `1:30am`, meaning this code will have to execute before then to work. If it executes after that, it'll default to the minimum timeout delay (varies, but less than `10ms`). A simple check to see if timeout is < 0 and if it is reset target to tomorrow. Eg:

```
if (timeout < 0) {
    target = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() + 1, 1, 30, 0);
    timeout = target.getTime() - new Date().getTime();
}
```

EDIT2: Also, keep in mind the client's PC needs to stay on your website the entire time for this to work (assuming this is client side script). If you need to ensure something happens whenever somebody is looking at the page at that time, then this is fine, otherwise, it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take in mind the async processes are pseudo async, i.e. when one occurs (like click, a timer firing, or an XMLHttpRequest) it is queued until there is resource to execute it (this varies from browser-to-browser). Because there is no actual threading setTimeout (in your case) is queued to be executed in next possible moment. When it occurs depends on the source code.

A good reading on the topic you could find [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/)

Answer (score -1):

```
 setInterval(function(){
 var d = new Date();
     if (d.getSeconds()==0) { 
        if (d.getMinutes()==30) {  
            if  (d.getHours()==1) {
                alert("Hello")
             }
         }
     }
 }, 1000);
```

Comment: If you do it this way (and you most assuredly SHOULD NOT DO SO, then you would need to capture the interval id (eg: `var intervalID = setInterval...`) and then clear the interval (eg: `clearInterval(intervalID);`) once you git the correct time.

Comment: It is already running after 1 sec. So we do not need any interval. I have tested the code myself

Comment: Your code is setting the interval to `1000`. So every second it checks to see if it is the right time. It'll only actually be the right time once per day, but it will still keep checking over and over and over and over again.

Comment: Moreover, your code is incredibly inefficient - it is creating a date object and doing some logic 86,400 times per day. It needs to do something exactly once per day. 86,400 times worse than ideal is generally regarded as poor (it will work, it's just a terrible way to do it).